# Она — прачка, он — ?

Tags: род-существительного

Интересно, если она — прачка, то он — прач, что ли?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такие слова называются словами без парных образований. Многие имена существительные, в большинстве случаев это слова мужского рода, обозначающие лицо по профессии, занимаемой должности, выполняемой работе, занятию, ученому или почетному званию и т.д., в официально-деловом стиле сохраняют свою форму и в тех случаях, когда относятся к лицам женского пола: педагог, депутат, физик и т. д. А исторически так сложилось, что  женщина занималась стиркой белья. Поэтому в момент обозначения этого действа (стирки) слово *прачка* "наградили" ж. р., без парного образования.

Answer (score 2):

Вот на что наткнулся:

[3.3.4. Группа непарных личных имен существительных женского рода](http://lit.lib.ru/m/martinowich_g_a/2rod_s.shtml)

> К ним, например, относятся: модистка, кружевница, сиделка, маникюрша, корсетница, манекенщица, белошвейка, прачка, посудомойка, балерина, машинистка. В отличие от непарных существительных мужского рода существительные женского рода никогда не могут употребляться для обозначения лиц противоположного (мужского) пола (исключение составляют только грубые, подчеркнуто метафорические употребления типа: баба! шляпа! и т. п. В этом случае возможны также существительные среднего рода: бревно! и т. п.). С этой целью в литературном языке обычно используют описательные обороты: машинистка -- переписчик на машинке (слово машинист имеет другое значение -- "механик, управляющий ходом машины"), доярка -- оператор машинного доения (последнее в официальном стиле может употребляться по отношению к лицам мужского и женского пола) и т. п. И только у единичных слов этой группы имеются соответствующие парные образования существительных мужского рода: доярка -- дояр, уборщица -- уборщик, медсестра -- медбрат.

Видимо, это пережитки тех времен, когда считалось, что только мужчина может заниматься серьезным делом =)

Comment: Так как же назвать мужчину - оператор прачечного дела?

Comment: Мужчину можно назвать прачкой или машинисткой. С тем же успехом, что и женщину - директором. Имхо.  
Единственный для меня спроный вариант - медбрат. Мне кажется это совершеннейше неудобоваримый эрзац. "Медицинская сестра" - советская замена для "сестра милосердия". Не *какая*, заметьте, сестра, а *чья*. Но милосердие после 17-го года было не в чести... По всему поэтому, медбрат выглядит чудовищно.  
Ну еще "балерун", но это и без меня известно, его и в словарях нет.

Comment: Кстати, о "медбрате". Нам, когда выдавали удостоверения в университете (после курса медподготовки), то даже парням писали "медсестра".

Comment: Хотя, кстати, по логике, действительно "прач". Ведь слово, как я понимаю, происходит от "прать" (по-украински "прати"), что значит "стирать".

Comment: Как назвать? В связи с новомодными тенденциями, видимо, что-то в духе менеджера по клинингу =)

Comment: Мы так договоримся до того, что сиделку-мужчину назовем оператором машинного сидения (©Грамота).